# Fatal error with StrImportXLSX in Phpmyadmin - Xampp

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

When I using Phpmyadmin with Xampp and I try to import a xlsx with strImportXLSX I read this error:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\string_mb.lib.php on line 29

My configuration is:

xampp\phpmyadmin\config.inc.php

$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 6000;

xampp\php\php.ini

post_max_size = 750M 
upload_max_filesize = 750M   
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000M

xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini

max_allowed_packet = 200M

xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\config.default.php

$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 6000;
```

In all ExecTimeLimit I have tried 0 and -1 but result is the same.

What can I do?
Thanks in advance,

Regards

Comment: The error clearly indicates the file name & line no.Refer that.

Comment: I think that the problem is to change time limit value, but i don't know what can i change.